# Shield ui grid hierarchy grid make non-editable while main grid editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, shieldui

I made rows of main grid editable and there is no need of editing rows in hierarchy grid.But the problem is once I click on a row of a hierarchy grid it becomes editable and value of a same column number of main grid will appear in the selected column of the hierarchy grid. Below picture attached here will make more sense.[image]

So as I mentioned I dont need this to be happened in the hierarchy grid.

**Here is my code so far....**

```
$("#allTransGrid").shieldGrid({
                                dataSource: {
                                    data: datad,
                                    schema: {
                                        fields: {
                                            mbr_id: {path: "mbr_id", type: String},
                                            lon_id: {path: "lon_id", type: String},
                                            center_name: {path: "center_name", type: String},
                                            grp_name: {path: "grp_name", type: String},
                                            mbr_name: {path: "mbr_name", type: String},
                                            lon_amt: {path: "lon_amt", type: Number},
                                            lon_int_amt: {path: "lon_int_amt", type: Number},
                                            loan_total: {path: "loan_total", type: Number},
                                            ind_inst: {path: "ind_inst", type: Number},
                                            today_pay: {path: "today_pay", type: Number, nullable: false},
                                            lon_id_as: {path: "lon_id_as", type: Number}
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                sorting: {
                                    multiple: true
                                },
                                paging: {
                                    pageSize: 12,
                                    pageLinksCount: 10
                                },
                                events: {
                                    editorCreating: function (e) {
                                        if (e.field == "ind_inst") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false, max: 1000};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "loan_total") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false, max: 500000};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "lon_int_amt") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false, max: 100000};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "lon_amt") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false, max: 100000};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "mbr_name") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "grp_name") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "center_name") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "lon_id") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "mbr_id") {
                                            e.options = {enabled: false};
                                        }
                                        if (e.field == "today_pay") {
                                            e.options = {max: 10000};
                                            console.log(e.options);
                                        }

                                    },
                                    detailCreated: function (e) {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: "PaymentCatcherGroupBy",
                                            cache: false,
                                            dataType: 'JSON',
                                            data: {loan_id: e.item.lon_id_as, c_id: center_id},
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                $("<div/>")
                                                        .appendTo(e.detailCell)
                                                        .shieldGrid({
                                                            dataSource: {data: data},
                                                            sorting: {
                                                                multiple: true
                                                            },
                                                            paging: {
                                                                pageSize: 5
                                                            },
                                                            columns: [
                                                                {field: "installment_num", title: "Week"},
                                                                {field: "installmentAmount", title: "Installment Amount"},
                                                                {field: "paidAmount", title: "Paid Amount"},
                                                                {field: "dueDate", title: "Date Paid", type: Date}
                                                            ],
                                                            events: {
                                                                editorCreating: function (e) {
                                                                    if (e.field == "installment_num") {
                                                                        e.options = {enable: false};
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                                alert('error');
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                },
                                selection: {
                                    type: "row",
                                    multiple: true,
                                    toggle: false
                                },
                                columns: [
                                    {field: "mbr_id", width: "100px", title: "Member ID", enabled: false},
                                    {field: "lon_id", width: "100px", title: "Loan ID"},
                                    {field: "center_name", title: "Center Name", width: "100px"},
                                    {field: "grp_name", title: "Group Name", width: "70px"},
                                    {field: "mbr_name", title: "Member Name", width: "170px"},
                                    {field: "lon_amt", title: "Loan Amount", width: "100px"},
                                    {field: "lon_int_amt", title: "Interest", width: "100px"},
                                    {field: "loan_total", title: "Total", width: "80px"},
                                    {field: "ind_inst", title: "Installment Amount", width: "120px"},
                                    {field: "today_pay", title: "Today Payment"}
                                ],
                                editing: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    event: "click",
                                    type: "cell"
                                },
                                scrolling: true,
                                height: 600
                            });
```

Any help would be appreciable. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable editing of the detailed grid:

https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/editing

or you can set editable to false to those columns you do not want to edit.

columns: [
    {field: "mbr_id", width: "100px", title: "Member ID", editable: false},

I hope this would solve your issue.